# How can I bind this jQuery event to a hover of a HTML element?

Tags: jquery, css

What is the syntax to get this bit of jQuery to call when say, h2.myClass is hovered?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
  $("div.clickme, div.clickMeTimes").fadeOut("slow", function () {
  $("div.clickme, div.clickMeTimes").remove();
  });

  }, 2500);
});
```

Thanks to all the answers, alot of them were very good but @SKS went the extra mile with my extra requirements. The below fades in my div in and out on mouse hover instead of the initial on page load.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('h2.myClass').hover (function() {
       $("div.clickme, div.clickMeTimes").stop(true).fadeOut("slow");
  }, function () {
       $("div.clickme, div.clickMeTimes").stop(true).fadeIn("slow");       
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want something to be executed only on mouse enter. You can just use `mouseenter` function.

I think below is what you want,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('h2.myClass').mouseenter(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
         $("div.clickme, div.clickMeTimes").fadeOut("slow", function () {
            $(this).remove();
         });
    }, 2500);
  });
});
```

Also modified `$("div.clickme, div.clickMeTimes").remove();` inside the callback to `$(this).remove()` which will remove the corresponding element instead of trying to remove both element.

Edit: Try below, If you it to fadeIn and fadeOut.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('h2.myClass').hover (function() {
       $("div.clickme, div.clickMeTimes").stop(true).fadeOut("slow");
  }, function () {
       $("div.clickme, div.clickMeTimes").stop(true).fadeIn("slow");       
  });
});
```

Comment: Nice - I think i'll accept this, but do you know how I can .show(); the div on mouseleave?

Comment: @SMacFadyen If you have something to do on mouse leave then you should use `hover`. But you are removing those div's? `.remove` will remove those divs from the DOM.

Comment: ok.. I just wanted it to toggle.. so maybe just .css(display: block;) and display: none; ?

Comment: Possibly, the div is shown and fadeOut on mouseenter. Is it possible to add the div back on mouseleave? essentially returning to the first state

Comment: @SMacFadyen See my edited answer at the end of my post. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for going that extra mile, SKS.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".myClass").hover(function(eIn) { // this is the function for when the mouse is hovered over the item
    //do work
},
function(eOut) {  // this is the func when the mouse leaves the item
    //do work
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("h2.myClass").hover(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
  $("div.clickme, div.clickMeTimes").fadeOut("slow", function () {
  $("div.clickme, div.clickMeTimes").remove();
  });

  }, 2500);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your logic in a function :

```
var fadeAndRemove = function() {

     setTimeout(function(){
         $("div.clickme, div.clickMeTimes").fadeOut("slow", function () {
              $("div.clickme, div.clickMeTimes").remove();
         });

      }, 2500);
}
```

then bind it to the hover event :

```
$("h2.myClass").on('mouseenter', function() {
     fadeAndRemove();
});
```

Use hover if you have somthing to do on mouseleave also.

Answer (score 1):

If you *just* need to make the hover work:

```
$("h2.myClass").mouseover(function(){
  $("div.clickme, div.clickMeTimes").fadeOut("slow", function () {
  $("div.clickme, div.clickMeTimes").remove();
});
```

Otherwise if you need to make it work AND stop the timer:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  timer = setTimeout(function(){

$("h2.myClass").mouseover(function(){
  clearTimeout(timer);
  $("div.clickme, div.clickMeTimes").fadeOut("slow", function () {
  $("div.clickme, div.clickMeTimes").remove();
});
```